# Matlab: Creating a video using VideoWriter

Tags: matlab, video, signal-processing, pixel, avi

How can I create an avi video in Matlab using the `VideoWriter` class, but defining its content pixel by pixel?

Having the original pixel by pixel, line by line information, is there any way to implement this on `Videowriter` when using `open`?

Comment: What do you mean "pixel by pixel"?  You can certainly write single *frames* in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use im2frame, something like

```
myVideo  = VideoWriter('c:\temp\myVideo.avi');
open(myVideo);
writeVideo(myVideo ,im2frame(rand(20,20,3)));
close(myVideo);
```